# Can't understand what this passage is trying to say

Tags: translation, words

I'm trying to understand the meaning of a beginning passage in a fashion magazine on a page about make-up.

> ”トレンドくすみカラーでこびないワタシ”
>
> くすんだピンクやラベンダー、ダスティーなピンクなど今まで手を出しにくかったちょっとくすんだ”オトナ色”で、ゴーイングマイウェイなこびないフェイス。

This what my interpretation of the passage is as far, I don't think it's correct in any way really.

> "I don't suit the muted colours trend."
>
> Using muted pink, lavender, dusty pink, etc hasn't suited me until now, slightly muted "adult colours" suits my face/doesn't suit my face.

I'm very confused as to what this means. I can't tell if it's talking about muted colours in a positive or negative way. I also cannot figure out the meaning of 手を出す and ゴーイングマイウェイ. I understand that it says "going my way" but I don't know what it actually means. I'm also not sure if I've properly understood the meaning of こびる either. I think in this context it's supposed to mean to flatter/to suit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ”トレンドくすみカラーでこびないワタシ”
>
> くすんだピンクやラベンダー、ダスティーなピンクなど今まで手を出しにくかったちょっとくすんだ”オトナ色”で、ゴーイングマイウェイなこびないフェイス。

Where to start?  Guess I'll start with 「こびる」 as it is a key word here.  Get that wrong and the whole passage will make little sense.  I am sure dictinaries will give you "to flatter" as that verb's first definition, but did it help you at all? I would highly doubt it.

「こびる」 in this context would mean along the lines of "***to play the kawaii girl (toward others around you)***" in my own words.  So, 「こびない」 means "not playing the kawaii girl".
What colors would most people expect the quintessential kawaii girl to wear?  Certainly not くすんだ ("dull, somber, etc.") colors, right?  Hope things are starting to make sense for you here.  This article is shouting "Cute, girly colors are no longer fashionable!"  Do I need to continue?

「手を出す」 here means "to try (new things)", "to attempt something."  What are the colors that little cute girls might not want to wear?  Dusty pink or lavender, right?  Wear those and you are no longer that kawaii girl you thought you would forever be!

「ゴーイングマイウェイ」 should mean "having one's own style", "not trying to please others", etc.

I am not translating the whole passage to save your question from looking like a TL request.  Just hope I covered the things that were holding you back.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah the dictionary really didn't help here.  I think I finally understand what this passage means :)